# changing the file extension from html to .asp lost all the style and image of the website

Tags: html, css, image, asp-classic

I have created  a Html file, and than i rename it with .asp as requires.I need this to upload it online .I have copy the HTML file and placed inside a ASP folder which contains the .asp files .However when i replaced with the existing one, my website was not looking good, images, text and all Looks different. some images are lost and text are not in style.

i have copy the CSS and image files from main to placed it inside a .asp folder still not solve my problems

Any shortcut method where i can do this?
What changes should I do before I change to asp

Comment: It sounds like the paths to your image and css files are incorrect in your new file. The paths need to be relative to the file they are being referenced in (your `.asp` file in this case). It would help if you actually put an example of the code in your question, together with an idea of the url of page in question (it doesn't have to be the real website, you could just replace the real server name with `example.com`).

Comment: Yep..I have edit the path path of the CSS file from the main folder..Problems has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Used this code it helps to produce the right result.This is the Code that needs to setup from the .asp folder which contains the .asp file to the main folder
an eg shown below

link href="../X/css/style.css" ... />